# Can't read a Milkshape 3D binary file correctly

Tags: java, file, binary

I hope you can help me with this:
I'm trying to write a Milkshape3D model loader for Java.
I have found the [Milkshape3D File Format Specification here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ms3d/ms3dspec.h)
and following it I created my code as belows, Im missing some classes still, but this problem came by now; with a DataInputStream object I should be able to read the file by whatever data type I want, like with readChar() I should be able to read all of the chars in the file header, wich should be "MS3D000000", but when I use readChar() to get only the "M", it returns a weird symbol, and even if I skip the first 10 bytes to read the version number, it returns a number very different than 3!!

I dont know what to do, can you explain me what am I doing wrong?
The model can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?rjles6exz8fsl62)

```
package milkshape3d_loader;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ms3d_header_t {
    char[]  id;         // always "MS3D000000"
    int     version;    // 3
    ms3d_header_t() {
        id = new char[] {'M','S','3','D','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
        version = 3;
    }
}

public class Milkshape3D_Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File inFile = new File ("dy_joey.ms3d");
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream (inFile);
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (inStream);

            char id = input.readChar();
            System.out.println (id);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readChar` reads two bytes and interprets them as a single `char` - a 16 bit UTF-16 code unit. The "weird symbol" is presumably U+4D53, the Unicode character represented by the bytes corresponding to ASCII M and S. You probably need to read each byte individually using

```
char id = (char)input.readUnsignedByte();
```

Comment: So I will have to do (char)input.readUnsignedByte() 10 times for reading each char in the id field of the header in the file?

Comment: and then for reading the next elements in the file I should have to read only by bytes without using readInt, readFloat and so on?

Comment: @user1968051 or you may find it easier to allocate a `new byte[10]`, use `readFully` to read 10 bytes into that and then `new String(bytes, "US-ASCII")` will give you a ten character String that you can compare to the expected signature.

Comment: @user1968051 for the rest of the structures you may be able to use `readUnsignedShort` etc. but bear in mind that this (and the other multi-byte reading methods) expects big-endian data, and from what I can tell the ms3d format is little-endian, so you'll need to byte-swap everything after reading it.

Comment: @user1968051 it means what it sounds like - in a little-endian format 16 bit values are stored with the least significant byte first followed by the most significant, `readUnsignedShort` expects MSB first followed by LSB, so after reading you need to swap the bytes over to get the correct value, e.g. `((val & 0xff) << 8) | ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8)`